# How can I get an offline version of wikitravel on my Froyo phone?

Tags: offline, browser-add-ons, wiki

I'm looking for a way to get an offline version of wikitravel on my Froyo phone (Desire if it makes any difference)

I know of wapedia, but I really need an offline copy of the site... Any obvious way to achieve that? Note that the stock browser doesn't even let you save single web pages!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [iTravelFree](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rezendi.itravel) app to save wikitravel pages and view them offline.

Comment: Wow, talk about a niche product.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggesting iTravelFree, that's my first choice. I stumbled upon a lower tech solution that might appeal some people:

[Oxygen Guide](http://code.google.com/p/oxygenguide/)

Which is a free mobile friendly dump of the wikitravel website.